# Нужно записать url который прислал пользователь, чтобы дальше работать с pytube

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, telegram, telebot

Есть бот, где пользователь выбирает режим скачивания и затем ему присылают сообщение : Жду ссылку. В этот момент нужно как-то записать значение которое написал пользователь в новую перменную чтобы дальше с ним работать. Как это реализовать?

```
import telebot as tb
import config
from telebot import types

bot = tb.TeleBot(config.TOKEN, parse_mode=None)  # Вызов бота по TOKEN


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def sendWelcome(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=1)
    download = types.KeyboardButton('Скачать')
    markup.add(download)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Привет, {message.from_user.first_name} ...', reply_markup = markup)
    bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, config.sticker_welcome)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def openSettings(message):

    get_message_text = message.text
    '''print(get_message_text)'''

    if get_message_text == 'Скачать':
        download_markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        video = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Видео \N{movie camera}', callback_data='video')
        audio = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Аудио \N{headphone}', callback_data='audio_link')
        download_markup.add(video, audio)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите формат скачивания', reply_markup = download_markup)
    else:
        pass


@bot.callback_query_handler(func = lambda call: True)
def download(call):
    if call.data == 'video':
        video_keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
        change_settings = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Изменить качество \N{gear}', callback_data='change_settings')
        video_link = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Вставить ссылку', callback_data='video_link')
        video_keyboard.add(change_settings, video_link)
        bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, '', show_alert=False)
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Желаете изменить качество?', reply_markup=video_keyboard)
    elif call.data == 'audio_link':
        bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, '', show_alert=False)
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Жду ссылку \U0001F9A7')
        while call.message == call.message.from_user:
            print(call.message.text)
    elif call.data == 'video_link':
        bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, '', show_alert=False)
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Жду ссылку \U0001F9A7')
    elif call.data == 'change_settings':
        bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, '', show_alert=False)
        config.settings(call.message)
    else:
        pass


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    elif call.data == 'audio_link':
        msg = bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Жду ссылку \U0001F9A7')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, audio)
    elif call.data == 'video_link':
        msg = bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Жду ссылку \U0001F9A7')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, video)


def audio(message):
   print('ссылка на аудио:', message.text)


def video(message):
   print('ссылка на видео:', message.text)
```

используйте `bot.register_next_step_handler()`

[документация](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py)